# Extracting .name from returned hash

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think this may be simpler than I am making it...

I currently have this in my controller (user)

```
  def portfolios
    @title = "Portfolios"
    @user = User.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
    @portfolios = @user.portfolios
    @collections = @user.collections.find_all_by_portfolio_id(1)
    @collections = User.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
    render 'show_portfolios'
  end
```

And this in my view:

```
  <% @portfolios.each do |portfolio| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= image_tag("portfolioIcon.png", alt: "Portfolio Logo")%></td>
      <td><%= portfolio.name %></td><br/>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <% (1..@user.collections.find_all_by_portfolio_id(portfolio).length).each do |collection| %>
        <td><%= @user.collections.find_all_by_portfolio_id(portfolio) %></td><br/>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

But it looks to return a hash that sits in square brackets:

```
[#<Collection id: 1, user_id: 1, portfolio_id: 1, name: "User-1-Portfolio-1-Collection-1", created_at: "2013-04-20 10:45:46", updated_at: "2013-04-20 10:45:46">]
```

so I can't just place .name at the end of it to return "User-1-Portfolio-1-Collection-1".

The database is set up so that: 
A User has many portfolios and many collections.
A portfolio belongs to Users and has many collections through a join table
A collection belongs to Users and has many portfolios through a join table

Hope this makes sense.

Maybe there is an easier way to extract the info I am after in an ordinary hash?

Comment: That's not a hash in square brackets, it's a single `Collection` object in an array, representing the row returned by a query. The object has been displayed by `inspect` so you can see the instance variables and their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value of portfolio is `[#<Collection id: 1, user_id: 1, portfolio_id: 1, name: "User-1-Portfolio-1-Collection-1", created_at: "2013-04-20 10:45:46", updated_at: "2013-04-20 10:45:46">]` and you wish to access the name of the Active Record object it holds, then you have to do `portfolio.first.name` since portfolio variable is an `array` in your case and not an Active Record object.

Doing `portfolio.first` will give you the first active record in that array.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That was exactly my issue! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your code:

```
@collections = @user.collections.find_all_by_portfolio_id(1)
@collections = User.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
```

You stomp on your first set of returned values in `@collections` with the line following it. You are wasting all sorts of CPU cycles and have a potential bug if one of those lines is supposed to be assigning to a different instance variable.